# Heat lines with MapServer

Tags: postgis, mapserver

Is it possible to do heat lines on MapServer similar to the following image. The datasource will be PostGIS.

[image]

Comment: What is the exact format of your data?

Comment: A list of distances along each line.  The distances will have a normal distribution along a line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data are points and your have the value of power as an attribute then you can. See the documentation about colorrange, datarange, and rangeitem in https://www.mapserver.org/mapfile/style.html.

The result is not as neat as in your image but it can be acceptable if you have dense points. It could look like this (image captured from a manual of another software, Reefmaster https://reefmaster.com.au/.

[image]

Colorrange takes just two colors so perhaps you can't have the similar scale as in your image. Also if the power value has been stored into vertices of a linestring as M coordinate (or fake Z) the MapServer can't help you. And if you have data as points you can do the same thing that colorrange does also by making a normal point layer that is classified by power. It would mean more work with writing the mapfile but also full control on the colors.